# Running ECMAScript 5 compliant javascript on Java 7

Tags: javascript, java, java-7, ecmascript-5

I would like to run javascript using the embedded javascript engine of Java 7. The code which I am trying to run is ECMAScript 5 compliant, which should not be a problem since the embedded Rhino's version is [1.7 release 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/New_in_Rhino_1.7R3) which supports it. Yet, running the following snippet doesn't work:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval("var char = 'a';");
```

It fails with the error `missing variable name` which indicates that `char` is a reserved keyword. However, the `char` is no longer reserved  in ECMAScript 5, so I am completely confused. The question is which javascript version is supposed to work with the embedded Rhino in java 7?

I am using java `1.7.0_80`, the language version reported by the engine is `1.8` and the engine version is `1.7 release 3 PRERELEASE`.

Comment: That script doesn't fail for me in Java 7 (OpenJDK, Linux). It works just fine.

Comment: @RealSkeptic indeed, it seems OpenJDK contains `Rhino 1.7 r4`. Since I can not move to OpenJDK I will try to use `Rhino 1.7 r4` as an external jar. Thanks for spotting this, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As @RealSkeptic pointed out, the embedded script engine of OpenJDK 7 (`Rhino 1.7 r4`) has no problem running the above javascript snippet. It seems that `Rhino 1.7 r3` can not run it, so running it using Oracle Java 7 needs the external Rhino of `1.7 r4` (or above) which can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino). Just for completeness, the java equivalent of the code in the question based on Rhino's own API looks like this:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;

public class Rhino {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Context context = Context.enter();
        try {
            ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
            context.evaluateString(scope, "var char = 'a'", "test", 1, null);
        } finally {
             Context.exit();
        }
   }
```

}

Note that the import declarations are important since the same classes are available bundled in the JDK within a different package:

```
import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context;
import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptableObject;
```

Importing them yields in using the embedded engine with Rhino's API which will not work.